# Magento 2.1 Web Setup Wizard Frozen to remove an extension

Tags: magento-2.1, web-setup-wizard

I installed the application YOTPO.  Then decided to remove it. 
The system is now stuck at this screen.  Therefore every time I go to **SYSTEM > WEB SETUP WIZARD**, it brings me to this screen and I can not get out...

[image]

**THIS IS FROM THE CONSOLE BOX:**  **Please Let me know if it is too much**

> [2017-03-15 19:02:04 UTC] Job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout
>   block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification
>   full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate
>   config_webservice"]" has been successfully completed [2017-03-16
>   20:16:32 UTC] WARNING: There is a problem with backup files!
>   Performing rollback from these files may cause the Magento application
>   to be unstable [2017-03-16 20:16:32 UTC] Backup file does not exist
>   for "db" [2017-04-17 23:02:02 UTC] Job "rollback
>   {"backup_file_name":"/home/tackworx/public_html/var/backups/1489555456_filesystem_code.tgz"}"
>   has been started [2017-04-17 23:02:02 UTC] Restoring archive from
>   "/home/tackworx/public_html/var/backups/1489555456_filesystem_code.tgz"
>   ...
>
> [2017-05-03 16:02:02 UTC] Update is already in progress. [2017-05-03
>   17:02:02 UTC] Update is already in progress. [2017-05-03 18:02:02 UTC]
>   Update is already in progress. [2017-05-03 19:02:02 UTC] Update is
>   already in progress.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the console log and paste what it says.

Comment: Done but i remove some useless success notifications, otherwise it would not have fit.

Answer (score 0):

if the application is enabled first disable it using this following command.

Login to your SSH and go to your magento root installation folder then type on SSH

```
php bin/magento module:disable Yotpo_Yotpo
```

Comment: That module is not there, I ran the module:status command to see all modules, so it has been removed but screen is still frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, remove the  update_in_progress.flag file from the /var directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all .files in `/www/html/magento/var` folder. I had same issue and I solved doing that:

[image: console]

```
sudo rm -rf .update_status.txt
sudo rm -rf .update_queue.json
sudo rm -rf .setup_cronjob_status
sudo rm -rf .type.json
sudo rm -rf .update_cronjob_status
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is working 
Did all mentioned ideas
Still update in progress

And now screen showing nothing and Magento admin platform not working